# Change specific element from ListView

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart, mobile

I have a ListView widget, which renders items based on an array. I want to change the background color from a specific item onTap.

I made a GestureDetector that wraps up the item inside the ListView, then onTap a variable (which I defined globally before, named backgroundColor) changes its value. But this changes the background color of all items, I want it to change the background color of just the specific item the user taps on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Share your code, It would be easier to answer and point out directly where your issue is being caused and thus, fixing it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declear a int like this

```
Int isselect=-1; 

Then 
Ontap:=> setstate(){
Isslected =index; 
}

Then you can how use that is selected as bool 

Like 

Is selected==index? Container(): sizebox(),
```

Sorry the way I write the code, I am on mobile that is why...

Hope it work well for you,
If yes. Mark and vote up.

Comment: You can even use to change the color... like this is.  .... color: Isslected==index: colors.red: colors.black

Answer (score 0):

Although it'd help greatly if you were to paste your code along with your question, I think 'index' could be your solution. Pass the index of the listview as a parameter in onTap and modify bgColor for that index alone.